# Pseudo elemet not showing with overflow-hidden CSS

Tags: html, css, overflow, pseudo-element

I might get a bit of flack for asking this question so I'll say this right away. The previous answers on Stackoverflow haven't worked.

I'm trying to have an image in the shape of a hexagon and for that, I want to have a `div` as the parent of the image.

I then used a CSS hexagon generator and added the CSS to my `div` element with `overflow: hidden`.

The problem: The only part of the hexagon that I can see is the main rectangle (the non-pseudo element) and not the two triangles on either side (the pseudo-element). I tried everything from changing position, getting rid of the animations, and adding the `overflow: hidden` to different parts.

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #64C7CC;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 173.21px;
    margin: 86.60px 0;
    
    &::after, &::before {
        // overflow: hidden;
        content: "";
        // position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        border-left: 150px solid transparent;
        border-right: 150px solid transparent;
    }
    &::before {
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    &::after {
        top: 100%;
        width: 0;
    }
    // // overflow: hidden;
    // z-index: 100;
    // position: relative;
    // background-color: aqua;
    // @extend hexagon;
}


.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div className="image-container" data-aos="fade-right">
   <img src='images/profile-pic.JPG' alt="profile pictures"/>
</div>
```

Result:
[image: Image only pops through the main div section, not the two triangle pseudo elements]

I hope you can help as I've been sitting at this for quite a while. If you need clarification please just add a comment and ill respond tomorrow morning.

Comment: i don't see any hexagon on your css, please provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img-hexagon hexagon1">
  <div class="hexagon-helper-1">
    <div class="hexagon-helper-2">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -300px;
}
.img-hexagon {
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hexagon-helper-1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon-helper-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYBwF.png);
    visibility: visible;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -80px;
}
```

Note that it only works with image applied as `background-image` from `css`

Comment: not exactly what I wanted because id rather have it as a single div but it works!  guess if you don't want a background-image, then the method with the pseudo-elements works better. Thank you very much though!